# DOM not rendering using componentFactory

Tags: angular

Requirement : Tring to open `ngx-extended-pdf-viewer` in pop window using Angular 9

Problem:

```
 `ngx-extended-pdf-viewer` couldn't loaded
```

In TS:

```
open(): void {
    const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(WindowComponent);
    let componentRef  = componentFactory.create(this.injector);
    this.applicationRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

    // get DOM element from component
    const domElem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef < any > )
      .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

    this.OpenWindow = window.open('', 'childwindow', 'width=400,height=400,left=150,top=200');
    this.OpenWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "";
    this.OpenWindow.document.body.appendChild(domElem);
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't work cause new window completely empty - I mean no resources are downloaded to it. And  you can insert angular component to a window without angular. I'm not sure that it will work, but I guess you could try to load script with angular framework code. Or just open your component in modal window

Comment: Have you solved this by now? Can you please post your code to show how you open a pdf in a new popup window?